# jQuery - Getting total depending on which checkboxes are selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes that represent various food items. I would like to create a subtotal depending on what the user selects. I have been looking through the jQuery documentation and I see how to update the the value of a textbox however how does one do a new tally every time a new checkbox is "checked". Also, what happens when a checkbox is "un-selected". Is there a way to store the value of each item in the HTML code of the checkbox?

I have a jsFiddle example I have been fooling with here ...

http://jsfiddle.net/fQTUp/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `value` with price to the checkboxes and count it. Here is: http://jsfiddle.net/fQTUp/9/

Comment: Excellent! I see now. I was looking for an if..then to check if the checkbox was selected. However, $("input:checked").each works so much better. Thanks a bunch for the great jsFiddle example.

Comment: I also have some option (radio) buttons (for mustard, ketchup. pickles, etc ..). Is there a way to exclude these from totaling since they do not represent a "value" as far as price goes? Right now they seem to be included in the collection of "checked" items. Is there a way to limit it to just checkboxes and not radio buttons?

Comment: yes, use in selector `$("input[type=checkbox]").click(...` insead of `$("input").click(...`

Comment: After some digging I found that I had to add the type=checkbox (as Samich mentioned) to the 'each' loop to prevent the values of the radio buttons from being used. I could also use $("input:checkbox:checked").each( ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RT4XS/

```
// When the page is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function(event) {
        updateTotal();
    });
});

function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $("#menu input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    $('#TotalCost').val("$" + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

You can put the price on the actual HTML elements as the value and then just iterate over the checked items adding up the price.